# Storybook.js is breaking fonts loaded via webpack

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix, storybook

I have a project using Laravel Mix and the Element component library - I've just installed Storybook, but the font files included in Element are no longer being loaded correctly in the browser (they're just showing up as empty squares).

Simply installing the below packages has somehow broken font loading (uninstalling them fixes it).

```
@storybook/addon-actions: "^6.0.21",
@storybook/addon-essentials: "^6.0.21",
@storybook/addon-links: "^6.0.21",
@storybook/vue: "^6.0.21",
```

After some research, I'm inclined to think that the problem is related to the webpack config - and something to do with how font files are loaded... I've tried adding the below to my webpack.mix.js file, which didn't work.

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                    loaders: ['file-loader'],
                    include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../')
                }
            ]
        }
```

Not sure what to try next! Any help would be appreciated :)